# If condition with select query in oracle

Tags: oracle

How to Use IF Condition with Select Query in Oracle. Please suggest

```
IF  (SELECT ptr_forecast_dt from ptr_details  WHERE ptr_line_id = prmptr_line_id AND ptr_actual_dt IS NULL) IS NOT NULL THEN
        SELECT ptr_forecast_dt INTO Forcast_dt  from ptr_details  WHERE ptr_line_id = prmptr_line_id AND ptr_actual_dt IS NULL;
    END IF;
```

Comment: Why do you want to check the value before putting it into your `Forcast_dt` variable?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add another condition in the WHERE clause, as below:

```
SELECT ptr_forecast_dt 
INTO Forcast_dt  
FROM ptr_details  
WHERE ptr_line_id = prmptr_line_id 
AND ptr_actual_dt IS NULL
AND ptr_forecast_dt IS NOT NULL;
```

If you want to insert an alternate value if ptr_forecast_dt is NULL, then you can use the NVL function, as below:

```
SELECT NVL(ptr_forecast_dt, TO_DATE('01/01/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
INTO Forcast_dt  
FROM ptr_details  
WHERE ptr_line_id = prmptr_line_id 
AND ptr_actual_dt IS NULL;
```